# Multi join query returns to many results and improperly matched

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following minimal schema in Oracle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1ed0/14

The queries I have run yield too many results and this query:

```
select cat.*, status.*, source.*
from cats cat, status status, source source
Left OUTER JOIN source source2
on source2.sourceid = 1
Right OUTER JOIN status status2
on status2.isStray =0
order by cat.name
```

will yield incorrect results.  What I am expecting is a table that looks like the following however I cannot seem to come up with the correct SQL.

```
NAME    AGE     LENGTH  STATUSID    CATSOURCE   ISSTRAY     SOURCEID    CATID
 Adam    1        25     null         null         null       1             2
 Bill    5        1      null         null         null       null          null
 Charles 7        5      null         null         null       null          null
 Steve   12       15     1            1            1          1             1
```

In plain English what I am looking for is to return all known cats + their associated cat source + their cat status  while retaining null values.  The only information I will have is the source that I am curious about.  I also only want the cats that have a status of either STRAY or UNKNOWN (null)

**UPDATE**

For clarification the mapping of Cats goes like this:

The id of the Cat is stored in the Source table under the column catId.
The Status table has a reference to the PK of Source as the column labeled catSource.

In practice  to get the Status of the current cat the query would be:

```
select cat.* from cats cat, status status, source source  
where cat.id = source.catId  
and source.sourceId = status.catSource
```

**FINAL QUERY**

```
select *
from source
    inner join cats on source.catid = cats.id
and source.sourceid = 1
    left join status on source.sourceid = status.catsource
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from source
    inner join cats on source.catid = cats.id
    left join status on source.sourceid = status.catsource
         and statusid=1
```

Comment: will supplying an arbitrary status of 'unknown' equate to null?

Comment: I don't see from your fiddle how cats related to status and source... If I could figure that, I could tweak the above

Comment: Ah.  So  the Source table has a sourceId column that maps into the Status table column of catSource.  Also the Source table keeps track of the Cat id

Comment: See edit above. You should use joins like above rather than a where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the help I made one slight tweak to it to reduce the result set.

Answer (score 1):

The expected data seems a little off. Check this query (using oracle syntax).

```
select c.name,
       c.age,
       c.length,
       s.*,
       src.*
  from cats c,
       status s,
       Source src
  where c.id = s.StatusId(+)
     and c.id = src.sourceId(+)
  order by c.name


Adam    1   25              2   2
Bill    5   1                   
Charles 7   5                   
Steve   12  15  1   1   1   1   2
Steve   12  15  1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: That is very close to what I am expecting.  There is a second Steve entry in your output.  Because of the reference to the the other source.